# Работа с ViewModel или перенос Бизнес-логики из активити

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel

Я начал переносить бизнес-логику из активити во viewModel, но остановился на одном месте. Мне нужно перенести этот участок:

```
repo.getMovieWithId(secondSorting)
            .enqueue(new Callback<Movie>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Movie> call, Response<Movie> response) {
                    List<MovieItem> movieItems = getMovieItemsFromResponse(response);
                    secondMovieAdapter.submitList(movieItems);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Movie> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

    repo.getMovieWithId(thirdSorting)
            .enqueue(new Callback<Movie>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Movie> call, Response<Movie> response) {
                    List<MovieItem> movieItems = getMovieItemsFromResponse(response);
                    thirdMovieAdapter.submitList(movieItems);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Movie> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

    private List<MovieItem> getMovieItemsFromResponse(Response<Movie> response) {
    Movie movie = response.body();
    List<MovieItem> movieItems = new ArrayList<MovieItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < movie.getResults().size(); i++) {
        Result result = movie.getResults().get(i);
        movieItems.add(new MovieItem(result.getTitle(),
                result.getReleaseDate(),
                result.getPosterPath(),
                result.getVoteAverage(),
                result.getId()));

    }
    return movieItems;
}
```

https://github.com/ploskiycherv/MovieApi

Но я не могу понять, как сделать так, что бы не создавать для каждого ресайкла новые переменные и методы во viewModel, а сделать это более автономно и компактней, без дублирования кода. 
Во MovieModel уже есть часть перенесенного кода, который ничем не отличается от тех, что нужно перенести:

```
public class MovieModel extends ViewModel {


private MovieRepo repo = new MovieRepoImpl();
private MutableLiveData<List<MovieItem>> movieItemLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public LiveData<List<MovieItem>> movieItemLiveData() {
    return movieItemLiveData;
}

public void getMovies(String sorting) {
    repo.getMovieWithId(sorting)
            .enqueue(new Callback<Movie>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Movie> call, Response<Movie> response) {
                    List<MovieItem> movieItems = getMovieItemsFromResponse(response);
                    movieItemLiveData.setValue(movieItems);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Movie> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
}

private List<MovieItem> getMovieItemsFromResponse(Response<Movie> response) {
    Movie movie = response.body();
    List<MovieItem> movieItems = new ArrayList<MovieItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < movie.getResults().size(); i++) {
        Result result = movie.getResults().get(i);
        movieItems.add(new MovieItem(result.getTitle(),
                result.getReleaseDate(),
                result.getPosterPath(),
                result.getVoteAverage(),
                result.getId()));

    }
    return movieItems;
}
```

}

Comment: у вас repo уже должен возвращать готовые данные.

Comment: т.е должен возвращаться некоторый класс обертка Result<List<Movie>>>, который может быть error, success и loading.

Comment: Да, но там данные зависят от String sorting, который я должен передать 3 раза